# Xquery grouping results based on condition

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a question on xquery grouping. From what I understand, the usual case would be to use `distinct-values` on the docs in the for loop, however as I have a condition to fulfill before grouping the values, and I am not quite sure how this can be done.

This is part of my xmldb:

```
<element tag="0001,0000" name="Pos1>198</element>
<element tag="0001,0001" name="Pos2">123</name>
<element tag="0002,0001" name="Pos3">433</element>
<element tag="000b,0000" name="Pos3">16</element>
<element tag="0005,0000" name="Pos4>532</element>
<element tag="0005,0001" name="Pos5">342</name>
<element tag="0008,0001" name="Pos6">17</element>
```

The condition to fulfill is that the x-coordinates (number or hexdec) have to be in odd values (e.g. from the above xml, i would only need results from tag="0001,...", tag="000b,...", tag="0005,..."), and then count how many items in each group.

This is how the results should look like:

```
<group>
<element xcoord="0001">2</element>
<element xcoord="000b">1</element>
<element xcoord="0005">2</element>
</group>
```

My xquery code so far looks like this, where I could generate results that have odd x-coordinates, but I have no idea how to proceed on from here for the grouping.

```
import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com" at "http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xq"; 

for $x in collection('/db/mapdb/')//element
let $coord := number(functx:substring-before-last($x/@tag, ","))
where $coord mod 2 != 0
return $x
```

Kindly advise me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This XQuery**:

```
for $x in 
  distinct-values(/*/*/substring-before(@tag,',')
                    [contains('13579bdf', 
                               substring(., string-length(.))
                              )
                     ]
                  )
 return
   <element xcoord="{$x}">
    {count(/*/*[$x eq substring-before(@tag,',')])}
   </element>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<element xcoord="0001">2</element>
<element xcoord="000b">1</element>
<element xcoord="0005">2</element>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, it works, and pretty consistent. Likewise to Alejandro's solution, I need to add a loop so that it could loop through to do the check against the tag. I wonder is it due to the eXist Xquery?

Comment: @jl: I always verify my solutions before I publish them. These results were actually produced -- when run with oXygen + Saxon 9.2.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

This XQuery:

```
<group>{
    for $key in distinct-values(/root/element/tokenize(@tag,',')[1])
                   [contains('13579bdf',substring(.,string-length(.)))]
    return <element xcoord="{$key}">{
               count(/root/element[tokenize(@tag,',')[1] eq $key])
          }</element>
}</group>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <element tag="0001,0000" name="Pos1">198</element>
    <element tag="0001,0001" name="Pos2">123</element>
    <element tag="0002,0001" name="Pos3">433</element>
    <element tag="000b,0000" name="Pos3">16</element>
    <element tag="0005,0000" name="Pos4">532</element>
    <element tag="0005,0001" name="Pos5">342</element>
    <element tag="0008,0001" name="Pos6">17</element>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<group>
    <element xcoord="0001">2</element>
    <element xcoord="000b">1</element>
    <element xcoord="0005">2</element>
</group>
```

**Note**: There is no built-in operator for xs:hexBinary data type except for `eq` and `ne`.

Comment: +1 for the only correct answer. A minor remark is not to use the general equality operator -- the value equality operator is most appropriate here and also more efficient. Another minor remark is about the unnecessary use of the longer overload of `substring()` and about the lack of consistency -- why didn't you use either only `substring()` or only `tokenize()` ?

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks. I take your remarks. About consistency: my goal was to clearly address the hexadecimal problem.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks. I am testing with eXist Xquery sandbox, had a little issue with the count. I added a loop to it like: count(for $x in /root/element/@tag where (tokenize($x,',')[1] eq $key) return $x) and it works perfectly thanks. + 1

Comment: @jl: That's strange! I've tested with XQSharp and Saxon. This is the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which processor you are using. I tested the following code on [try.zorba-xquery.com](http://try.zorba-xquery.com/) (it should also work for Saxon or other processors supporting XQuery 1.1 and XPath 2.0):

```
let $xmldb :=
  (
    <element tag="0001,0000" name="Pos1">198</element>,
    <element tag="0001,0001" name="Pos2">123</element>,
    <element tag="0002,0001" name="Pos3">433</element>,
    <element tag="000b,0000" name="Pos3">16</element>,
    <element tag="0005,0000" name="Pos4">532</element>,
    <element tag="0005,0001" name="Pos5">342</element>,
    <element tag="0008,0001" name="Pos6">17</element>
  )
for $x in $xmldb
let $coord := tokenize($x/@tag, ",")[1]
group by $coord
where contains('13579bdf',substring($coord,string-length($coord)))
return <element xcoord="{$coord}">{count($x)}</element>
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: `where number($coord) mod 2 != 0 `  -- this obviously doesn't work with a number represented in an hexadecimal format.

Comment: The OP probably doesn't have an XQuery 3.0 processor, so this excludes the possiblity to use `group by` .

Comment: I am using eXist DB for the Xquery sandbox, but I do not think there is a group by function for this processor, which comes much handy with SQL.

Comment: @jl: Ok. I leave the reponse here for others. Could be useful for them. Cheers.

Comment: @Dimitre: I fixed the odd/even thing with Alejandro's proposal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XQuery 1.0 processor then the usual pattern for a group by is:

```
let $values := ...
for $key in distinct-values(for $value in $values return my:key($value))
let $group := $values[my:key(.)=$key]
return ...
```

where `my:key` is a function/expression that obtains the key for each input value.

In your case you can fill in the pattern as so:

```
for $coord in distinct-values($xmldb/(tokenize(.,",")[1]))
let $x := $xmldb[tokenize(.,",")[1] = $coord]
return <element xcoord="{$coord}">{count($x)}</element>
```

Whether or not this perform efficiently depends on your implementation.  I have written a [blog post](http://xqsharp.blogspot.com/2010/05/join-optimizations-in-xqsharp.html) on how to write a group by that XQSharp will recognise.

**Edit:** I missed the requirement that all x coordinates must be odd.  This can be fixed with the addition of a where clause to constrain the last character of the coordinate:

```
for $coord in distinct-values($xmldb/(tokenize(.,",")[1]))
where contains('13579bdf',substring($coord,string-length($coord)))
let $x := $xmldb[tokenize(.,",")[1] = $coord]
return <element xcoord="{$coord}">{count($x)}</element>
```

Comment: Is this syntactically correct: `let $x := $xmldb[tokenize(.,!,!)[1] = $coord]` . In particular, what is the meaning of the exclamation marks?

Comment: This answer doesn't meet the requirement that only odd values of the x-coordinate should be considered in the grouping.

Comment: @Dimitre: The exclamation marks should have been quotes - I have fixed this typo!

Comment: @Dimitre: I missed the "odd" condition - I have fixed this too.